# Yii2 Sessions Timeout when browser closed?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm wondering about Yii2 framework's session timeout

When browser is closed will the session data get unset automatically?

Can this be set if browser is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Session variables only work when browser is open. When you close the browser, it will be destroyed. If you want to preserve information, you must use cookies.

From Yii2 docs:

> You can get the cookies in the current request using the following
>   code:

```
// get the cookie collection (yii\web\CookieCollection) from the "request" component
$cookies = Yii::$app->request->cookies;

// get the "language" cookie value. If the cookie does not exist, return "en" as the default value.
$language = $cookies->getValue('language', 'en');

// an alternative way of getting the "language" cookie value
if (($cookie = $cookies->get('language')) !== null) {
    $language = $cookie->value;
}

// you may also use $cookies like an array
if (isset($cookies['language'])) {
    $language = $cookies['language']->value;
}

// check if there is a "language" cookie
if ($cookies->has('language')) ...
if (isset($cookies['language'])) ...
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookies